# How to convert a list to a data frame in python?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, class, data-cleaning

So, I have a list that look some thing like this:

```
      name=[["product 1",15,male,yes]
             ["product 2",10,female,yes]
             ["product 2",10,female,yes]
             ["product 3",none,female,yes]
             ["product 4",20,yes,male]]
     and so on...
```

And I wish to use an class function to get the result like this:

```
 [Item("product 1",15,"male","yes"), 
  Item("product 2",10,"female", "yes"), 
  Item("product 2",10,"female", "yes"), 
  Item("product 3",none,"female","no"), 
  Item('product 4",20,"male","yes")...so on]
```

Next I wish to remove part where there is a missing element:

```
[Item("product 1",15,"male","yes"), 
 Item("product 2",10,"female", "yes"), 
 Item("product 2",10,"female", "yes"), 
 Item('product 4",20,"male","yes")...so on]
```

For product 4 the order have been changed. There are others like product 4, out of order as well (the way they are out of order different as well.)

I have done some preparation for the "class", but I am not sure what to do form here:

```
class Item():
__name = ""
__cost = 0
__gender = ""
__prime = ""

def __init__(self, name, cost, gender, prime):
    self.__name = name
    self.__cost = cost
    self.__gender = gender
    self.__prime = prime
```

Can anyone show the Python code to do it ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: just use dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is pretty obvious, isn't it?  I think you're making it harder that it needs to be.

```
timr@tims-gram:~/src$ cat x.py
name=[
    ["product 1",15,"male","yes"],
    ["product 2",10,"female","yes"],
    ["product 2",10,"female","yes"],
    ["product 3",None,"female","yes"],
    ["product 4",20,"male","yes"]
]

class Item():
    _name = ""
    _cost = 0
    _gender = ""
    _prime = ""

    def __init__(self, name, cost, gender, prime):
        self._name = name
        self._cost = cost
        self._gender = gender
        self._prime = prime

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Item({self._name},{self._cost},{self._gender},{self._prime})"

mylist = [Item(*k) for k in name if k[1]]
print(mylist)
```

Output:

```
timr@tims-gram:~/src$ python x.py
[Item(product 1,15,male,yes), Item(product 2,10,female,yes), Item(product 2,10,female,yes), Item(product 4,20,male,yes)]
timr@tims-gram:~/src$
```

Comment: Should there be an extra step to add "private variable for an layer of  security for the data?" or have it already be secured.

Comment: "Secured" from what?  This is just a data structure in a Python script.  What attack vectors are you imagining?

Comment: oh, it was because I though Python gives us the ability to create 'private' methods and variables within a class by prepending double underscores to the name.

Comment: That's just a convention.  Python doesn't have any privacy controls on classes.

Comment: oh, I see. Thank you for the clarification.